# Converting simple layout table to div width not working maybe tables are best

Tags: html, css, web

I am one of those using tables for everything, but now when some table attributes has been deprecated I feel obligated to switch to divs CSS so I have a simple layout table I need to change to divs and I cannot make it to work as I need.

The 3 column layout must have: left column 200px width and 100% height, right column must be also 200px width and 100% height but the middle column I will put content there so it must be 100% width that means if the screen is 1200px it will take 200px to left column 200px to left column and middle content column will auto-be 800px and so on, also with 100% height.

Here is what I did but cannot make it to work:

```
<style type="text/css">
.table {display:table;width:100%;min-width:1000px;height:200px;}
.row {display:table-row;}
.columna {display:table-cell;background:#666666;width:200px; float:left; margin-left:0px; height:100%;}
.columnb {display:table-cell;background:#cccccc;width:100%;height:100%;}
.columnc {display:table-cell;background:#666666;width:200px;float:right;margin-right:0px;height:100%;}
</style>

<div class="table">
<div class="row">
<div class="columna">a left column</div>
<div class="columnb">b middle column</div>
<div class="columnc">c right column</div>
</div>
</div>
```

For some reason I cannot understand the middle column is not using the correct height, its bigger I don´t know why. Also I cannot make it to respect the 100% height neither.

Any ideas?

EDIT

here is a demo Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/4xcg1eng/

The only way I can fix it is with div inside divs, almost the same crap as using tables but tables are even easier. I think those saying divs are best are wrong

Comment: This is exactly why I did not wanted to change from tables to divs, they are so complicated

Comment: I strongly recommend you look into `Bootstrap`.  So easy to use and also web responsive.  Plus plenty of support for any issues you have here on SO.

Comment: I preffer running tables I dont like bootstrap, more files to add more time to load and my customers only uses tablets and PCs because they don´t like how pages on bootstraps looks like neither

Comment: If you remove the style tags (<style type="text/css"></style>) from your fiddle the columns have the same height?

Comment: Anniemac no it changed now, the text fall down the one in the middle to bottom but the width and height changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a working model using the `display:table` property.

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
}

.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.row {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.columna {
    background:#666666;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 200px;
}
.columnb {
    background:#cccccc;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.columnc {
    background:#666666;
    width:200px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="columna">a left column</div>
        <div class="columnb">b middle column</div>
        <div class="columnc">c right column</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I would recommend you look at using a grid layout similar to [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com). If you are used to working in tables, the grid system should resonate a little with you.

Comment: This answer was just too good :), the other fix fixed it but started giving me problems with other divs, this one respects other divs I have on header and footer I see the light now with divs. So you just don´t need to set width to the middle container?

Comment: If you need it to be a little more responsive don't forget you can change the divs to {display: block; width: 100%; } with a media query

Comment: Just a small extra fix: is it possible to set the height of this layout to 100% so it uses the entire screen down?

Comment: Answer updated - just alter the 'table' height value and ensure there is a 100% height on html,body on your document.

Answer (score 0):

Did some edits to it in a fiddle here and got it working, let me know if this is what you were looking for :)

https://jsfiddle.net/fe0ftxh0/

The CSS looks like this now

```
<style type="text/css">
   .table {width:100%;height:200px;}
   .columna {background:#666666;width:20%;float:left;height:100%;}
   .columnb {background:#cccccc;width:60%;float:left;height:100%;}
   .columnc {background:#666666;width:20%;float:left;height:100%;}
</style>
```

Comment: try this fiddle, added some jQuery to handle dynamically figuring out the window size and subtracting the other two columns from it https://jsfiddle.net/fe0ftxh0/7/

Comment: If this is a simple one off change that solution would work, but if you are doing a lot of this try Bootstrap its much easier to work with and has responsive tables built in.

Comment: Almost the best fix. It works fine untill you resize the window and then it looks pretty bad but nice way. Maybe if I set display to inline-block?

Comment: It looks bad if you re-size the window as a developer would. But if you resize the window and then do a refresh it adapts and changes to the new viewport. Which unless your customers are shrinking their viewports then they will always have the proper display.

If you want this to re-size itself with the window as you drag it larger or smaller then this solution need more work

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle here with a working solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/4xcg1eng/17/

You can achieve exactly what you are looking for without using display:table.  The trick is the order in which you float your elements.  Your markup needs to specify column a and column c above column b.

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="columna">a left column</div>
    <div class="columnc">c right column</div>
    <div class="columnb">b middle column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

specify column a to float left, column c to float right, and add left and right margins equal to the widths of columns a and c to column b.

your css gets much simpler:

```
.table { height: 200px;}
.row {height: 100%; }
.columna {background:#666666; width:200px; float:left; height:100%;}
.columnb {background:#cccccc; height:100%; margin-left: 200px; margin-right: 200px;}
.columnc {background:#666666; width:200px; float:right; height:100%;}
```

You do not need to specify 100% width for divs -- they are automatically 100% width unless you specify otherwise.

I agree that using floating DIVs to do column-style layout is hard to wrap your head around if you are used to table layout.  But once you get used to it, it will free you from the being constrained by the table grid, especially when you need to reconfigure your layout for various sized screens.

You may want to consider using the flexible box model to achieve what you are after.  This is the kind of situation it is well suited for.

Comment: Wow ! Awesome ! I was almost giving up and keep using tables. So display:table tablecell are not really needed for layouts? Just a small thing: The height 100% is impossible right?

Comment: height 100% is possible.  It's just a matter of 100% of what... When you specify 100% for height it is 100% of the container.  In the fiddle above, the out DIV is set to a height of 200px... div.row uses height 100% which inherits the height of its parent -- div.table.  Similarly div.columna, div.columnb and div.columnc inherit div.row's height.

Comment: To add to the above comment, I realize you might have been wondering how to make the DIV 100% of the screen size... that's a little trickier, but still possible.  If you specify 100% height for div.table, it expands to 100% of the document's content... which in this case will be one line of text.  CSS3 offers the vh unit which basically means percentage of the height of the viewport.  100vh = screen height.  Here's an update to your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4xcg1eng/18/